# How to disable file download from website?

Tags: file, download, directory

I have some mp3 files on my website that I want to stream using SCM music player, but if I set a password for the directory, or redirect method then the streaming is obviously not working. Is there any other way I can disable file download but still be able to stream the files through the music player?

SOLUTION:

I disabled indexing using this `.htaccess` line:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Can you put your files in a db and load them on demand?

Comment: Not sure how to do that, you mean through mysql? I have no knowledge on dbs. But still wouldn't that create the same issue? If I password protect the folder will the database work?

Comment: No the data will being the DB and they can only get it through your player.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put

```
<Files ~ "\.(mp3)$">
    Order allow,deny 
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

in to your .htaccess, this will probably also denies mp3 for your music player, but u can easily configure .htaccess to allow mp3 from your ip or domain

Answer (score 0):

store your files in database instead of directory